# GeoDjango: keep geo data in DMS (Degrees Minutes Seconds) NOT decimal degrees

Tags: django, geospatial, geodjango

TL;DR: **how do I make geodjango to keep my data in DMS format**?

---

I'm building a simple django (GeoDjango actually) app that loads some external data source which contains coordinates in DMS format.

Currently, while loading that file, I convert the DMS to DD, in order to store that data as POLYGON field in django model.

However, for outputting (exporting to a file) I need to **convert it back to DMS**. This causes the outputted coordinates to be a bit different than the ones on the input. I believe this is due to floating number inaccuracy ...

Comment: Can't really do anything unless you can show us an example of conversion failing

Answer (score 1):

Just maintain the degree, minutes, seconds info and do a one-way conversion to decimal degrees for point manipulation in a method with a property decorator.

```
from django.db import models

class PolygonPoint(models.Model):
    parent_poly = models.ForeignKey(PolyModel)
    degrees = models.IntegerField()
    minutes = models.IntegerField()
    seconds = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def point(self):
        """
        Do conversion to point here
        """
        ...
        p = Point(x, y, srid=a)
        return p
```

Or, just keep maintain the data in a JSON blob.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    dms_points_json = models.TextArea(help_text=u"JSON list of dms polygon points")
    poly = models.PolygonField()

    def populate_poly(self):
        """
        Perform steps to update/populate the PolygonField using 
        dms_points_json blob
        """
        ...
```

Comment: thats not the proper way, for several reasons: for single Model I keep a Polygon (which consists of multiple Points), that would require me to write some related PolygonPoint model to store the DMS values. Moreover, I'm using geo-queries so I need to store it as regular PolygonField anyway.

Comment: it's up to you how you do it, this is one suggestion.

Comment: you could store all the dms values in a JSON CharField, or TextArea field, and have methods to parse out those values.